# What is the geometry problem banned by the Turkish government?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, popular-math

It is being reported recently ([example](http://web.archive.org/web/20161014135036/http://www.economist.com/news/europe/21708693-two-cheers-hypocrisy-turkeys-bid-join-eu-bad-joke-dont-kill-it)) that the Turkish government has banned a geometry textbook because the letters $FG$, which are the initials of an alleged plotter of the 2016 coup d'etat attempt, appear as a line in a diagram.

What is the problem or diagram that was suppressed?  What is the textbook?

Comment: Not a mathematical question.  Please move to the appropriate rubric.

Comment: It is within the scope of (popular-math) (reference-request) such as  other questions asking about math references from the Simpsons.

Comment: So are they going to ban Euclid's Elements?  See e.g. [Book 1, Proposition 36](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI36.html).

Comment: OP, can you please cite a source for this report? No matter the language.

Comment: Economist a few days ago.  @EvanAad

Comment: @RobertIsrael, it's possible they are checking lists of authors against lists of Gulen supporters and removing those books.

Comment: Do you mean [this article](http://www.economist.com/news/europe/21708693-two-cheers-hypocrisy-turkeys-bid-join-eu-bad-joke-dont-kill-it)? "Official paranoia scales heights of absurdity: last week a textbook was banned for using the letters “f” and “g”, Mr Gulen’s initials, in a geometry puzzle."

Comment: Yes. Thanks.  Link added to question.  @EvanAad

Comment: My initial reaction would be to ask this on [skeptics.se].

Comment: Your link does not lead to the article, but rather to the front page of The Economist's website.

Comment: @EvanAad, it leads to the article after some delay.  I converted it to an archive.org link.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, on a math site the reference-request for a controversial or apocryphal statement can always be interpreted as "where did this claim enter the literature", with analysis of the veracity of the claim a separate issue that (if not resolved on the math site) can be left for skeptic, fact-checking or topic-specific forums.  If somebody answering the reference-request question has evidence that the claim is false, of course that is a good answer anywhere that the question appears.   But deciding the truth or falsity is not strictly necessary here.

Comment: Agree to disagree that.

Comment: Google translate "G-spot" quote was worth it, in either case.   I'm a satisfied customer.  @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is what you are looking for: 
http://turkeypurge.com/turkey-bans-math-textbooks-due-to-questions-including-gulens-initials

Comment: That's it.   Thank you.   Unless somebody names the textbook or provides the complete problem this will be the accepted answer.

Comment: @zyx, I'm afraid you have been fooled. That article is obviously a joke.

Comment: @zyx: Running the Turkish article through Google Translate, it does not appear that the article states that the textbook under consideration was a geometry textbook. All it says is that it was a mathematics textbook ("Matematik kitabında"), and that the offensive problem started with "From point $F$ to point $G$" ("$F$ noktasından $G$ noktasına doğru"). It might have been an Algebra textbook with a problem along the lines of "A train goes from point $F$ to point $G$ at $100$ mph."

Comment: It also translates the same phrase as "for the right point to the G-spot". https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=tr&u=http://www.diken.com.tr/darbenin-getirdikleri-f-noktasindan-g-noktasina-yazan-matematik-kitabi-iptal/ @EvanAad

Comment: Interesting that the points on the line, in order, are FMG, with the M the other initial of the same person.